# Regex - match only the second finding

Tags: python, regex, text

I am trying to make a regex code that will select from the second "ITEM1" to the first "ITEM2".
Example:

```
ITEM1. text i don't want to find.
ITEM1.  text I want to find

ITEM2.  outside text

ITEM2 outside tex
```

Up until now, I came up with the following code:

```
(ITEM1)[\s\S]*?(ITEM2)
```

This select everythin from the first ITEM1 to the first ITEM2. I need the code to select between the second ITEM1 and the first ITEM2. 
Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?s)ITEM1(?:(?!ITEM1).)+?(?=ITEM2)
```

Start with `ITEM1`, lazily repeat characters that don't include the phrase `ITEM1` (to ensure that only the *second* instance of `ITEM1` gets matched), with lookahead for `ITEM2`.

```
match = re.search(r'(?s)ITEM1(?:(?!ITEM1).)+?(?=ITEM2)', str)
```